# Difference between color and colorscheme in `.vimrc`

Tags: vim

What's the difference between the commands `color` and `colorscheme` as used in `.vimrc`?

Just curious since the `README.md` for [Janus: Vim Distribution](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) uses `color`, whereas the `README` for [Solarized Colorscheme for Vim](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/vim-colors-solarized) uses `colorscheme`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
:colo[rscheme] {name}
           Load color scheme {name}.  This searches 'runtimepath'
           for the file "colors/{name}.vim.  The first one that
           is found is loaded.
```

Abbreviation for `colorscheme` is `color`

Answer (score 0):

I think that VIM tries to use the command that is appropriate. If there is only one command that starts with `color` (here `colorscheme`), then it allows to shorten up to the point where it is no more unique. <del>If have tried to use only `col`, and that fails, because there is another command `colder`.</del> The last sentence was mostly speculation, so see the comment of @ZyX for the real reason.

So `color` and `colorscheme` are the same as long as there is no other command beginning with `color`.

Comment: Rules here are more complicated for built-in commands: for example, `:e` is `:edit`, but there are also sets of commands starting with `:echo`, `:end`, `:exit` command and so on. It is true though for user-defined ones: 1. exact match is prefered. 2. if there is no exact match, only non-ambigious truncations are allowed.

Comment: By the way, `:col` fails not because there is another command `:colder`. It fails because you have empty quickfix stack which is explicitely stated in fail message: “E380: At the bottom of quickfix stack”. Non-empty stack is required for `:colder` command which is executed because `:col` is an abbreviation for `:colder`.

Comment: Good research, thank's for the comments. Will update my answer, though.

Comment: Third is that Bram is very strict in keeping backwards compatibility. `:colorscheme` -> `:color` truncation is not a bug and is documented, thus you should expect `:color` work as `:colorscheme` in every next vim release no matter whether there are new commands starting with `:color`. Command with full name `:color` also won’t be added for backwards compatibility reasons.